# Cursor of SQLite Query call that does not find anything matching the query criteria

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

What would a query call return if the query criteria isn't found in the table. Will the cursor returned be null? This is done in android.

Example:

```
Cursor c = rawQuery("SELECT c_name, FROM my_table, WHERE c_name = ?", "johnny");
```

What if there is no johnny in the column c_name? Will the cursor value be null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A valid cursor will be returned, but it will contain no results. So checks like

```
if (c.moveToFirst())
```

will return false.

Comment: You have to be aware that the cursor could be null, once you are sure the cursor is not null, moveToFirst is the correct way of checking it.

Comment: the cursor is really not not supposed to be null. only a non-null cursor with zero elements (moveToFirst returning null) truly indicates that the request found no matches. otherwise, it can be some other problem.